# How can I recover 1 year of chat history from skype (My PC has formatted recently)

Tags: windows-7, windows, skype

I recently formatted my system and in the process reinstalled Skype. I want to recover the previous one year's Skype call history that I had before formatting. Is it possible to restore it in any way?

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

If your computer got formatted, the files needed to fetch the history are no longer there unless you use some forensics tools to "undelete" the files. This may not work since it's possible the files have already been overwritten. You can try using such a tool to restore your Skype db files located in the `%userprofile%\appdata\` folder.

You can also send the drive to a data recovery specialist (usually starts at around $500-$700) to see if the data can be professionally recovered.

Skype does not keep conversation history on their own servers, so there is no way to contact them to get it back.

Comment: Is it possible to recover after getting the permissions legally?

Comment: If Skype doesn't store the conversations there is nothing to recover.  I haven't used this since Microsoft bought Skype, but for future use, there's a program called Skyperious that can extract and export conversation history.  It may not work now if Microsoft changed how Skype stores its conversations locally.  This won't help you recover anything now but possibly can help in the future.